# undefined values as error

Tags: php, html

I am new to this form and to php. I have got this code but always I got these errors.

```
Notice: Undefined index: id 
Notice: Undefined index: name
Notice: Undefined index: remarcs
Notice: Undefined index: test_res
Notice: Undefined index: date
Notice: Undefined index: phone_num
Notice: Undefined index: file
```

I have this html code of the form:

```
<form action="/clinic form/insert/insert.php" id="Form2" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="c">
<div align="center">
<?php echo "Insert information about a new Patient "?>
<table class="imagetable" border="1" cellspacing="3"  align="center">
  <th>Personal Informations</center></th>
<th>Test Results</th>

<tr><td>Name<br>
  <input type="text" class="large-fld" name="name" placeholder="Patient Name"></td>
<td>Remarcs:<br>
  <textarea type="text" cols="40" rows="5" class="large-fld"  name="remarcs" placeholder="Remarcs"></textarea></td>
  <tr><td>Address<br>
  <input type="text" class="large-fld" name="address" placeholder="Address"/>
  </td>
<td>Test<br>  <textarea type="text" cols="40" rows="5" class="large-fld"  name="test_res" placeholder="Test Result"></textarea></td></tr>
</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>Phone Number<br>
  <input type="text" class="large-fld" name="phone_num" placeholder="Phone Number"/>
  </td>
<th>Files</th>
</tr>
  <td>Date<br>
  <input type="text" class="large-fld" name="date" id="date" placeholder="0000-00-00"/></td>
<td>Echo Files:<br>
      <input type="file" name="file" id="file"/><br></td>
  </tr></th></table>
  <div class="row" align="center">
<input type="image" name="login" value="Login" src="images/insert.png" width="widthInPixels" height="heightInPixels" onMouseOver="this.src='images/insertRoll.png';" onMouseOut="this.src='images/insert.png';"> </td></tr>
      </table></div>
</form>
```

And this html code that I found it online:

```
<?php 
require_once ('../include/global.php'); 

$name = ''; 
$remarcs = ''; 
$address = ''; 
$test_res = ''; 
$date = ''; 
$phone = ''; 
$new_path = ''; 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

if (isset ($_POST['name'])) { 
$name = $_POST['name']; 
} 
if (isset ($_POST['remarcs'])) { 
$remarcs = $_POST['remarcs']; 
} 
if (isset ($_POST['test_res'])) { 
$test_res = $_POST['test_res']; 
} 
if (isset ($_POST['address'])) { 
$address = $_POST['address']; 
} 

if (isset ($_POST['date'])) { 
$date = $_POST['date'];
$desiredFormat = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($date));

} 

if (isset ($_POST['phone_num'])) { 
$phone = $_POST['phone_num']; 
} 

$path = "../uploads/".$_FILES['file']['name'];
//$path2 = "../uploads/".$_FILES['echo_photo']['name']; 
$ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

//if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $path.'_'.time().date().$_FILES['file']['name'])){ 
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $path.'_'.time().date().'.'.$ext);
$new_path = "./uploads/".$path.'_'.time().date().'.'.$ext; 
$sql="INSERT INTO patients (name, echo_files, remarcs, test_res, date, address, phone_num)
VALUES  
('$name', '$new_path', '$remarcs', '$test_res', '$desiredFormat', '$address', '$phone')"; 

$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die('Unable to execute query. '. mysqli_error($con)); 

if($result){ 
/*echo $name."<p>\n</p>"; 
echo $remarcs."<p>\n</p>"; 
echo $test_res."<p>\n</p>"; 
echo $address."<p>\n</p>"; 
echo $phone."<p>\n</p>";*/ 
header("location:insert_done.php");

} else { 
header("location:insert_false.php");} 
}

?>
```

Can someone tells me what is wrong with this code ?

Comment: where is your <form> ?

Comment: I didnt paste it sorry

Comment: where did you get your $tbl_name ?

Comment: From global.php, sir, now when I click the insert button nothing happens. I got a blank page. It should go to insert_done or insert_false

Comment: Plz confirm about your form that you have provided a name attribute value for all fields as you retrieve form value in your above code because this type occurs in this case..

Comment: change your mysqli_query($con,$sql) to mysqli_query($sql,$con)

Comment: I will edit my post to the new code

Comment: change your mysqli_query($con,$sql) to mysqli_query($sql,$con)

Comment: I cahnged it and still got a blank page and it is not redirecting the header page nor giving me an sql error

Comment: Well this happens only when  I upload a file , it give a blank and nothing added, but if I did not submit a file, it gives me an error :  Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given ...

Comment: In your form I am not able to see any input with name 'submit', in this case if(isset($_POST['submit'])) will be false. Debug the value of $_POST['submit']

Comment: I dont need a submit button, the button is an image when i click on it it will go to insert.php

Comment: I fixed now when only I upload a file to insert it with the informations it goes to blank page without redirecting nor seeing an error

Answer (score 0):

Its because, you are trying to get `$_POST` ed variables before form submit.

Try this:

```
if (isset($_POST['YOUR_SUBMIT_BUTTON']) {
  $remarcs = $_POST['remarcs'];
  // Your other variables which are posted.
  // Place all your code you need to execute after form submit.
}
```

Another thing is that you are using `date` as one of your field.

It is a [reserved keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) in MySQL.

You should enclose it with backtick (`) to avoid conflict.

Corrected Code:

```
<?php 
require_once ('../include/global.php'); 
$name = ''; 
$remarcs = ''; 
$address = ''; 
$test_res = ''; 
$date = ''; 
$phone = ''; 
$new_path = ''; 
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '';
    $remarcs = isset($_POST['remarcs']) ? $_POST['remarcs'] : '';
    $test_res = isset($_POST['test_res']) ? $_POST['test_res'] : '';
    $address = isset($_POST['address']) ? $_POST['address'] : '';
    $phone_num = isset($_POST['phone_num']) ? $_POST['phone_num'] : '';
    $date = isset($_POST['date']) ? $_POST['date'] : date('d/m/Y', strtotime($date));
    $path = "../uploads/".$_FILES['file']['name'];
    $ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    //if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $path.'_'.time().date().$_FILES['file']['name'])){ 
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $path.'_'.time().date().'.'.$ext);
    $new_path = "./uploads/".$path.'_'.time().date().'.'.$ext; 
    $sql="INSERT INTO patients (name, echo_files, remarcs, test_res, `date`, address, phone_num)
                VALUES  
            ('$name', '$new_path', '$remarcs', '$test_res', '$desiredFormat', '$address', '$phone')"; 
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die('Unable to execute query. '. mysqli_error($con)); 
    if($result){
        header("location:insert_done.php");
    }
    else { 
        header("location:insert_false.php");
    } 
}
?>
```

Comment: sir, I fixed what you said, now when I click the insert button nothing happens. I got a blank page. It should go to insert_done or insert_false but it didnt.

Comment: You need a little modification. You need to place your code for insert after submit. Otherwise, it will always run errors.

Comment: I did it sir and I got what I said: blank page.

Comment: Well this happens only when  I upload a file , it give a blank and nothing added, but if I did not submit a file, it gives me an error :  Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given ...

Comment: still got a white blank page

Comment: Any help about this ?

Comment: Set php's error reporting on and see the errors. Also, check if the code flow is proper.